# How to test code that relies on a SoftReference?

Tags: java, unit-testing, garbage-collection

I have certain code that uses many instances of a `SoftReference` subclass. I would like test that it works correctly in cases when all / only some / none of these references are staged for clearing in `ReferenceQueue`. For the case of "none" this is quite easy: create strong references to the objects, and the soft references are guaranteed to stay. However, how would I go about guaranteeing them to be cleared? As I understand, `System.gc()` is only a request to run garbage collector, and even if it actually runs, it may well decide to not collect all unreachable objects...

Also the code is quite performance critical, so it's not a good idea to alter it just for testing purposes. (Adding a test-only method that doesn't affect other methods is fine, but adding paths that are used only for testing in other methods is something to avoid).

Comment: I suggest to mock SoftReference class

Comment: @talex They want to actually test the `SoftReference`. How would mocking it help?

Comment: Sorry i miss interpret question. Now I have another question: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an option to access your `SoftReference` instances from the test you could simulate the GC behavior by calling methods directly on the `SoftReference` instances.

Calling `SoftReference.clear()` would correspond to the first step where the reference is cleared. Then you could call `SoftReference.enqueue()` to enqueue it in the reference queue, corresponding to the enqueing step the GC does [some time] after clearing the reference.

Calling these methods on a subset of your `SoftReferences` you could simulate that only some of the references have been cleared and enqueued.

I really think the above approach is to recommend since you got control of which references are cleared and that is a good thing in a test.

However, if you can not access your `SoftReferences` directly you are pretty much limited to allocating memory in an attempt to make the GC clear them. For example, as illustrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785713/how-to-make-the-java-system-release-soft-references/3810234#3810234) question and its answers.

Comment: This sounds good, I didn't know you could enqueue references manually. As I said, it is not a problem to add test-only code to the class in question as long as "normal" code is not affected, and I guess adding something like `enqueueReferencesTo (Set <?> ...)` will do it.